# How to throw exceptions with meaningful messages in F#?

Tags: c#, exception, f#

How to throw meaningful exceptions in F# and catch them in C#?

With the following code:

F# Library:

```
module Test

exception TestExc of string

let throwit message : unit=
    raise (TestExc("custom exception with message: " + message))
```

C# Client:

```
namespace TestExc
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Test.throwit("Hi there");
            }
            catch (Test.TestExc te)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Caught exception with message: " + te.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following message:

```
Caught exception with message: Exception of type 'Test+TestExc' was thrown.
```

But I want to see `Hi there` as the caught exception message.

What is the F# equivalent of the following?

```
class CSTestExc:System.Exception 
{
        public CSTestExc(String message) : base(message) { }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than creating exception using `exception TestExc of string` create exception as :

```
type MyExp (msg:string) = 
        inherit Exception(msg)
```